# Is it okay to say "15 minutes of four" in English?

Tags: word-usage

Is it okay to say "15 minutes of four" in English meaning "3:45"? Or would it mean "4:15"? Or is it totally incorrect to say that?

(I heard once a native speaker said that, but I am not sure if that was him just playing with words or that was an acceptable way of saying the time in English)

Comment: I've never heard anybody say that, usually it's a quarter past four or a quarter to four.

Comment: It can also be “fifteen minutes until four” or “fifteen minutes before four”.

Comment: In my section of the country, the word **minutes** is typically not present with **of**, though it is present with **to**.  *What time is it?  -- It's ten of eight.*  or *It's a quarter of eight* or *It's ten minutes **to** eight*.

Comment: I was about to answer with "No, you can't say that" until I saw others say otherwise! :D So it's worth noting that that phrasing is an [_Americanism_](https://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2006/08/telling-time-and-dates.html) — if you said "15 minutes of four" to me in the UK/Ireland, I'd presume it was because you learned the phrase wrong (or, if you mumbled, I might think you were saying "15 minutes after 4" quickly or something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the entry for *of* on [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/of), you’ll find:

> Before; until: *five minutes of two*.

Therefore, I’d regard the phrasing you ask about to be grammatical. However, I don’t generally hear that wording used with the fraction *quarter*. As said in the comments, phrases like:

- quarter to four
- fifteen minutes before four

are more common.

As for whether this person was using that phrasing to be humorous, you’d have to ask your friend. It might be colloquial.

Comment: I can't see that text if I follow your link.

Comment: @user133831 - The link works fine for me. In any case, OneLook is just an online dictionary, and the page lists several meanings for the word _of_. Also, I've copied the one most relevant to this question.

Comment: Weird - it must display different content to different people for some reason. I get the entry for "of" but not with that usage.

I'm a native speaker and have lived in multiple English speaking countries and not only haven't heard the expression I wouldn't be sure what was meant if I did. I assume it is dialectical and would be interested in seeing its spread but I can't actually find any usage - hence being curious about the dictionary entry to see where it is used.

The closest I could think of would be something like "5 of the 10 minutes remaining" but that's not quite the same thing.